# jQuery hover length giving different values on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, hover

I'm working with jQuery's following piece of code:

```
$('.myClass:hover').length()
```

This value is supposed to give 0 when my mouse is not on my element, and 1 when it is. I use this property to change some display parameters in my application. I found out that my code, though seemingly correct, didn't work with Firefox.

This led me to a more general problem : **in some particular cases, jQuery's hover length doesn't give the same value in Chrome and Firefox**. The case I'm encountering is when my mouse leaves the element and I catch this very event.

Here is a very simple snippet of code replicating the problem by alerting the value:

```js
$('#imagetest').mouseleave(function(){
  alert($('#imagetest:hover').length);
});
```

```css
.img-container{
  width:300px;
  height:150px;
  background-color:blue;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.img-container img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-container">
  <img id="imagetest" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/sunset_winter_shadows-wallpaper-1366x768.jpg">
</div>
```

The problem can also be seen in this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khv0jLk5/). When you leave the image zone to the right, the value remains 1 on Firefox and becomes 0 on Chrome. However, when leaving the image zone in the direction of the CSS or JS code zone, the value becomes 0!

Thank you for your help, that would be much appreciated.